# Windows 2012 ( Upgrade from Windows 2008r2 ) , Update Error : 800F0922

Tags: windows-server-2012, update

I've upgraded my Windows 2008r2 to Windows 2012 (non R2) . All went fine .
Then I used the WSUS Offline Updater (https://www.wsusoffline.net/) like I did beforehand on many other servers to update it .

This installed approx 120 Missing Updates , after it completed the system rolled back some of the updates . (just like with the other system, so I expected this) 
After this I was left with 40 updates , but at least now Windows update was working correctly with the WSUS Server.

So I started up the Windows Update and tried to install the rest of the updates... all went fine until I got to update :

KB4520007 , this update wont install I always get the Rollback and the error : 800F0922 .

Then I googled, and found something about Secure Boot error, and about a possible solutions by simply installing Bitlocker without actually configuring it . So I did that . But it did not help. I also looked in the BIOS and for the life of me I was not able to locate any Secure Boot settings. (it is a Fujitsu Primergy RX300 S6 )

Right now I cannot install any updates ... and I cant install Desktop Experience. I tried to install the update manually, I tried to run WSUS Offline update. I also tried to stop Windows Update Service, deleted the Software Distribution Folder. But always the same error.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: well , life is strange . I wanted to check the CBS logs... so I went on to delete everything in the c:\windows\logs\cbs folder and then try to install just one update to see what happens . And I have no idea if that was the culprit (would be strange) but suddenly a third update showed up ... KB2975331 after I installed just this update with success.. the rest of the updates installed as well... pffff